# Saving Bitmap as byte array results in weird file size

Tags: c#, bitmap, windows-10, file-storage

I am doing some testing for a future project, in which I will be creating an image encryptor. Right now I just wanted to get together a way of converting a bitmap to a byte array, save it to a text file, reload it, and resave it under a different name. I got it to work...there is just a problem with the file size afterwards. My converted image(The one that read from a byte array to create the image) is showing a larger file size than the original image. Here is my code:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            /**
             * Load the bitmap and convert it to a byte array
             * then save the file to the desktop
             */
            byte[] imageBytes = ImageToByte( new Bitmap( "C:/Users/Krythic/Desktop/NovaEngine.png" ) );
            File.WriteAllBytes( "C:/Users/Krythic/Desktop/NovaImageData.txt" , imageBytes );
            /**
             * Load the saved image bytes, then convert them back into an image and save it to the 
             * desktop under a new name.
             */
            byte[] convertedImageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("C:/Users/Krythic/Desktop/NovaImageData.txt");
            Bitmap image = ConvertToBitmap(convertedImageBytes);
            image.Save("C:/Users/Krythic/Desktop/ConvertedImage.png");
        }

        public static byte[] ImageToByte( Bitmap img )
        {
            ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
            return ( byte[] )converter.ConvertTo( img , typeof( byte[] ) );
        }

        private static Bitmap ConvertToBitmap( byte[] imagesSource )
        {
            ImageConverter imageConverter = new ImageConverter();
            Image image = ( Image )imageConverter.ConvertFrom( imagesSource );
            return new Bitmap( image );
        }
    }
```

I think the problem is due to the image.Save(); function, which...I think...is not picking the optimal compression for the image. Maybe I am wrong? Here is a picture of the property pages for both images:
[image]

You will also notice that the saved byte array version of the original image is showing a larger file size. **Why is this? Shouldn't the size of the file remain constant across the entire span of conversion?**

***Update: I'm pretty sure that the functions that I am using to convert the image are using poor conversion techniques. This would explain why the size of the original png differs from the byte-array-file version, which should be equal. So to solve this, I need an efficient, or correct way of doing the same thing that those two functions do.***

Answer (score -1):

Most likely the original file was somehow compressed , and re-writing the file ends up saving an un-compressed file because C# is not very smart about that.

and if C# was updated somehow and got better from the last time I used it, it is possible because you are converting a PNG into a bitmap (the bitmap is not size efficient) and then you save the bitmap to a PNG

Comment: I created the original image using GIMP, when created it I chose "9" as the compression level. Do you know what level C#/.NET chooses by default?

Comment: none . it saves all of the data , without compression

Comment: "none it saves all of the data, without compression" that is an incorrect statement. The size of the file without compression is: 2.23MB. I just tested this.